# Using the Dcast function (reshape2) on large dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, dcast

I have a dataframe that has dimensions of (325,928 x 2).

Below is a very small subset of that data:

```
Destination = c('A60001', 'A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001',
            'A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001',
            'A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001','A60001',
            'A60001', 'A60002', 'A60002','A60002','A60002','A60003')
Source = c('AA53', 'AA582', 'AA18', 'AA388', 'AA841', 'AA72', 'AA19', 'AA77', 'AA78', 'AA20', 'AA21',
       'AA12', 'AA412', 'AA634', 'AA591', 'AA859', 'AA157', 'AA254', 'AA167', 'AA176',
       'AA428', 'AA538', 'AA268', 'AA196', 'AA1250', 'AA23', 'AA16', 'AA692', 'AA196',
       'AA22')

df = data.frame(Destination, Source)

> df
   Destination Source
1       A60001   AA53
2       A60001  AA582
3       A60001   AA18
4       A60001  AA388
5       A60001  AA841
6       A60001   AA72
7       A60001   AA19
8       A60001   AA77
9       A60001   AA78
10      A60001   AA20
11      A60001   AA21
12      A60001   AA12
13      A60001  AA412
14      A60001  AA634
15      A60001  AA591
16      A60001  AA859
17      A60001  AA157
18      A60001  AA254
19      A60001  AA167
20      A60001  AA176
21      A60001  AA428
22      A60001  AA538
23      A60001  AA268
24      A60001  AA196
25      A60001 AA1250
26      A60002   AA23
27      A60002   AA16
28      A60002  AA692
29      A60002  AA196
30      A60003   AA22
```

Ultimate goal here is to transform this dataframe into a new dataframe using something similar to dcast because dcast cannot handle large amounts of data.

So here was the original code that I tried with this dataframe:

```
test<-dcast(cbind(df,V1 = rep(1,nrow(df))),`Source` ~ Destination,value.var='V1',fun.aggregate = length)
```

Output:

```
   Source A60001 A60002 A60003
1    AA12      1      0      0
2  AA1250      1      0      0
3   AA157      1      0      0
4    AA16      0      1      0
5   AA167      1      0      0
6   AA176      1      0      0
7    AA18      1      0      0
8    AA19      1      0      0
9   AA196      1      1      0
10   AA20      1      0      0
11   AA21      1      0      0
12   AA22      0      0      1
13   AA23      0      1      0
14  AA254      1      0      0
15  AA268      1      0      0
16  AA388      1      0      0
17  AA412      1      0      0
18  AA428      1      0      0
19   AA53      1      0      0
20  AA538      1      0      0
21  AA582      1      0      0
22  AA591      1      0      0
23  AA634      1      0      0
24  AA692      0      1      0
25   AA72      1      0      0
26   AA77      1      0      0
27   AA78      1      0      0
28  AA841      1      0      0
29  AA859      1      0      0
```

It works with the dataset I am providing but when I test it out with the full dataset of dimensions: `325,928 x 2`, R crashes. Is there a better function that can produce the same output but handle larger amounts of data. If this isn't enough information, I can provide the full dataset privately to whoever thinks they can solve this ( i can't provide it here because StackOverflow can't read all the data) so you can test out the issue directly from the source.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You might try the `dcast` function from `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks. How would you do that in this case? I'll try it on the larger dataset @Imo

Comment: I think the original data format is much much better than the wide one. If you need the wide one for some sort of analysis, maybe look into sparse matrices...? `325928^2`, the potential size of your output, is unwieldy to say the least.

Comment: I need the wide one ultimately because I am going to be converting it into a correlation matrix in the end along with applying hierarchal clustering. So it definitely needs to be in that final format. But based on @Imo 's comment, if there is a function in `data.table` that can perform the same thing on a much larger dataset then that would work best in my case

Comment: I am also not familiar with sparse matrices so if you think that is better than data.table then I will look into that also @Frank

Comment: Also the sparce matrix would have to have 0 instead of just a dot. @Frank

Comment: The dot represents a zero, the default value in a sparse matrix, I think; I rarely use them myself. Another possibility: if your sources and destinations belong to the same set of things, maybe you should be looking at this as a directed graph instead.

Comment: @Frank the directed graph is also something I am working on with this dataset but even with that, I still need the missing values to be represented as a 0 originally. I really appreciate the feedback by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Imo suggestion, this is the new solution to solving this:

If your dataset is very large/wide, convert your dataframe to a data.table and then from there

```
library(data.table)
df1<-setDT(df)
new3$value<-1
trial<-dcast(new3, Source ~ Destination, fill = 0)
```

This will give you the same result and can handle large amounts of data